# Clustering data with categorical and numeric features in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am currently looking for an Algorithm in Apache Spark (Scala/Java) that is able to cluster data that has numeric and categorical features.

As far as I have seen, there is an implementation for k-medoids and k-prototypes for pyspark (https://github.com/ThinkBigAnalytics/pyspark-distributed-kmodes), but I could not identify something similar for the Scala/Java version I am currently working with.

Is there another recommend algorithm to achieve similar things for Spark running Scala? Or am I overlooking something and could actually make use of the pyspark library in my Scala project?

If you need further information or clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Spark has K-means for clustering data, wouldn't that fit your needs ?

Comment: @dumitru As far as my research goes kMeans is not suitable for categorical data - even if you convert them to numeric values somehow the result is not that meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need first to convert your categorical variables to numbers using [OneHotEncoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) then, you can apply your clustering algorithm using mllib (e.g. [kmeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html)). Also, I recommend doing [scaling or normalization](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#standardscaler) before applying your cluster algorithm as it is distance sensitive.

Comment: One hot encoding to deal with categorical variables is a horrible idea. Gowers distance is a better approach. Can be used with K-prototypes or PAM